# How does a Fresnel rhomb work (half and quarter wave plate)?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, wavelength

How does a [Fresnel rhomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_rhomb) work (half and quarter wave plate)?

I am aware of [birefringence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birefringence), which creates a phase shift of $\Delta\phi=\dfrac{2\pi\Delta nL}{\lambda_0}$. But this doesn't explain how a plane polarised light shifts it's polarization angle after a half-waveplate or how a linearly polarised light becomes elliptical after a quarter-waveplate.

For the half one let's assume that wikipedia has an answer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveplate but why this electric field

$E(\hat{f}+i\hat{s})e^{i(kz-\omega t})$ describes an elliptical polarised light?

What I need is a mathematical description of how the retarders work...

Comment: Have you taken a look at this in the literature? This is explained for instance in E.Hecht: Optics. Are you asking how a Fresnel rhomb works or how wave plates work? Both can be described with the equation you posted, so I don't get what you are asking for.

Comment: There are several formalisms for describing the polarization of light. one of them is the [Stokes formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters). Another one is [Jones calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus). There is still more, for instance the Mueller Matrix formalism. You can transform all of them into each other. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: sorry, I could have written an answer by now. check out this [wolfram demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PolarizationOfAnOpticalWaveThroughPolarizersAndWavePlates/). It's for a polarizer, but just exchange the phase shift and the you get the math for a wave plate.

Comment: @sebastian: Thank you very much for your comments! What I actually need is to take an linearly electric field, make it pass through a quarter/half wave plate and see that the output is either shifted linear or circularly polarised.

Comment: Ok, so I don't know how much time you want to put into this. I wrote a bachelor thesis about this topic. It includes some calculations and references. this is the [link](http://quantum-technologies.iap.uni-bonn.de/en/component/publications/?task=download&file=216&token=294e84a6672a486d881880d560973c68). I'd love to help you out with actual calculations, but I'm just on my mobile right now. But the general way to proceed is $E_{out} = Q^{-1}  E_{in} Q$, where Q is the matrix for the retarder and E is your wave (in either formalism, Jones or Stokes, I favour Stokes),

Comment: @sebastian: I don't want something colmplicated like that. All I need is to start with a field like $\mathbf{E}=E_x \cos{kz - \omega t}+E_y\cos{kz-\omega t}$, to pass through a waveplate and see whether what's going out is a linear or circular polarised light.

Comment: ok, then Jones calculus should suffice. Check out this [link](http://electron6.phys.utk.edu/optics421/modules/m7/Jones.htm). you could choose to not do this with Jones vectors. then you would have to treat the x and y component of the E field separately, applying the respective phase shift.

Comment: I realize your post is very, very old, but you can get the mathematical description you seek, at an easily understandable level, from the two book references I give in my recent answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/692315/313612.