# Calculate the diffraction vector from arbitrary incident direction

Tags: geometric-optics, diffraction

I need to ray trace polychromatic light through an optical system that includes reflective diffraction gratings. I got stuck here.

If I have a reflecting plane with normal $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ and an incident wave described by wave vector $\mathbf{k_i} = (2 \pi / \lambda) \ \mathbf{\hat{k}_i}$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength and $\mathbf{\hat{k}_i}$ is the normal of the incident ray, I can get the wave vector of the reflected wave as

$$\mathbf{k_r} = \mathbf{k_i} - 2\mathbf{\hat{n}}(\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{k_i})$$

Here $(\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{k_i})$ is the component of $\mathbf{k_i}$ perpendicular to the surface and the $-2\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ factor "reflects it back up".

If I now add a periodic 1D grating of period $d$ to the surface such that the reciprocal vector of the grating $\mathbf{g}$ is in the plane ($|g| = 2 \pi/d$), the specularly reflected wave vector $\mathbf{k_r}$ is now also the 0th order diffracted wave vector.

But now I'd like to calculate vectors for the $\pm1$ orders by somehow adding $\pm\mathbf{g}$ and I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

Since diffraction doesn't change the wavelength, $|k_{+1}| = |k_{0}| = |k_{-1}| = |k_{i}|$.

Do I take the component of $\mathbf{k_r}$ parallel to $\mathbf{\hat{g}}$ (i.e. ($\mathbf{k_r} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{g}})$)  and add $\pm \mathbf{g}$ to it, then just *somehow* foreshorten the components perpendicular to $\mathbf{g}$ to keep $|k_{+1}|$ and $|k_{-1}|$ equal to $|k_i|$?

If that's the right idea, and I'm not sure of that; how would that be written **in vector form?**

**update:**

I've gone through [Born & Wolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Optics) and [Eugene Hecht's Optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_Hecht#Books) (and several other optics tomes nearby on the shelf) and was not able to find anything I can apply in this case. **Textbooks like to stick to the simpler case** where $\mathbf{g}$ is in plane of incidence, where the solutions reduce to the simple, familiar [grating equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_grating):

$$d(\sin \theta_i - \sin \theta_m) = m \lambda$$

---

Related in History of Science and Mathematics SE:

- [Where does "the grating equation" come from? Does it have a another name?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12591/3869)

Comment: ${\bf k'} = {\bf k_{\rm i}} + \bf g$ is the diffraction condition and $\bf k\cdot \hat g$ give the phase information.

Comment: In his book Onde elettromagnetiche, edition 1953 pp 211-215  Toraldo di Francia derives the formulas you are asking about. He also published two articles around the same time in English , https://opg.optica.org/josa/abstract.cfm?URI=josa-40-9-600 and https://opg.optica.org/josa/abstract.cfm?URI=josa-43-5-368, indicating the derivation but without the details. If interested, I suggest you start with the two articles in the JOSA, and if you are still interested I will post the relevant pages from the book. It is in Italian but there is always google translate...

Comment: @hyportnex OK, I don't have access from home but the library opens in several hours and I'll check the JOSA articles out. It seems that there are several copies of *Onde elettromagnetiche* in both Italian and translations in English in Taipei and other nearby cities, so I may be able to enjoy those as well this weekend. *Thanks!*

Comment: In the Italian edition it is under Capitolo X Diffrazione: paragraphs 12, 13,14 (Chapter 10 Diffraction) but I suggest that you read the whole chapter to get a flavor of his notation. To understand his derivation you have to know the Malus-Dupin theorem. Great stuff, enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK got it.

Split off the parallel and perpendicular components of the incident wave vector (and then throw away the original perpendicular part).

$$\mathbf{k_{i∥}} = \mathbf{k_{i}} - \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ (\mathbf{k_{i∥}} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}})$$

Add the point in reciprocal space to it:

$$\mathbf{k_{∥m}} = \mathbf{k_{i∥}} + m\mathbf{g}$$

then get the new perpendicular component by giving it the direction of the *outwards-pointing* normal and whatever magnitude adds up to the initial $|k_i|$:

$$\mathbf{k_{⟂m}} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \ \sqrt{|\mathbf{k_{i}}|^2 - |\mathbf{k_{∥m}}|^2}$$

and add the parallel and perpendicular components back together.

$$\mathbf{k_{m}} = \mathbf{k_{m∥}} + \mathbf{k_{m⟂}} $$

Adjust the sign convention for the direction of $\mathbf{g}$ to taste.

When the expression under the square root goes negative, you've got an evanescent situation, and for free-space ray-tracing purposes on a macroscopic scale, you terminate the ray at this point.

The intensities of all the propagating (non-evanescent) orders will sum to the incident intensity.

Comment: my memory may be fading but isn't the case that when you write $\mathbf{k_{m∥}} = \mathbf{k_{i∥}} + m\mathbf{g}$, etc., you are implicitly assuming a "photon" momentum interaction?

Comment: @hyportnex well there are all kinds of physical phenomena that are by necessity swept under the rug in geometrical optics, right? I'm not really thinking of this as a momentum vector so much as I am thinking of it as a direction vector $\mathbf{\hat{k}}$ but keeping track of the wavelength in my geometrical ray-tracking program (mentioned in the question) by keeping the wavelength information as the magnitude. That way when I get to an interface where wavelength matters (most of them) it's right there.

Comment: @hyportnex I can implement Snell's law for refraction or the grating equation (here) in vector form and don't have to use those pesky trigonometric equations so popular before digital computers were invented and optical folks were [writing with feathers using light from burning animal fat](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6347/3869). This method does not allow for inelastic scattering (e.g. Raman) or elastic recoil of the macroscopic components (e.g. Mössbauer if my photons were very high energy) or anything else. It's just geometrical optics, "spelled with a $\mathbf{k}$".

Comment: @hyportnex but to answer your question directly, I don't know. *Am I?* I think I'm just assuming that I have an infinitely wide beam and ignoring diffraction effects that would be due to the finite size of my beam and grating. Once again, geometrical optics, not physical optics.

Comment: Exactly my point: "It's just geometrical optics" and equating $\mathbf k$s is momentum balance, that is the geometrical optics of gratings, as you sweep everything else under the rug, and it works!  Nothing wrong with that but I was under the impression, wrongly it seems, that you wished to *understand* the derivation how to prove that result from principles of wave propagation (diffraction and interference).

Comment: @hyportnex first sentence "I need to ray trace polychromatic light through an optical system that includes reflective diffraction gratings. I got stuck here." doesn't seem to leave room for that impression, nor does "If that's the right idea, and I'm not sure of that; how would that be written in vector form?" I need to do the ray tracing to further understand the dispersion that my femtosecond EUV beam experiences as it reaches the sample and how that interacts with the acceptance of the electron spectrometer in order to better interpreted the data and understand the band structure.

Comment: @hyportnex please, if you have a more informative answer, do post it and I'll read it carefully and learn from it! I think of light in the simplest of physical optics terms - it's a wave and we can get by most of the time just solving for the electric field. I use apodization, Fourier transforms - (both normal [and fractional](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/646133/83380)) and other wavy concepts to get my optics done. But if there's more to learn here, please do share!

Comment: you are right and my reading was superficial, it wasn't the first time and it won't be the last....

Comment: @hyportnex btw the reason I like this form so much is that it works surprisingly well if you relax the constraints - instead of a plane you can have a curved or wavy surface $s$ and instead of parallel periodic lines your grating can vary in pitch and direction across $s$ such that the vector field $\mathbf{g}(x)$ represents the gradient of the local periodicity. As long as it doesn't vary too rapidly, ray tracing in this situation still gets you very close to the full-blown physical optical numerical results, at least spatially. Of course details of grating lineshapes are a different matter.

Comment: This is exactly what Toraldo di Francia derived directly from Maxwell's equations, and based all his theory of diffraction/scattering on it. It fell out of favor and, sadly, got quickly forgotten shortly after Keller, who just about the same time introduced his so-called "Geometrical Theory of Diffraction", [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_theory_of_diffraction).

Comment: @hyportnex I'm slowly getting my [round tuit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round_tuit) and reading these papers. Yes I see what you mean! Fyi in Math SE [Doubt about Malus Theorem. (Optics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4690233/284619) may be related.

Comment: roundtuit, eh? never heard that term, one always learns something new every day... am glad you like Malus-Dupin. In college physics class I myself had no clue what the big deal was about that until decades later I encountered it in this [context](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1144543/) by Ronchi &  Toraldo, which was my first real "optics" stuff as such... I think you will enjoy the beauty of it!

Comment: see also this [question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/whatever-happened-to-parageometrical-optics-of-diffraction) where at least one user @Conifold knew the subject; he also referenced Cornbleet that is indeed an excellent resource regarding quasi-optical techniques in reflector antennas. Now I will have to on check on Kummer, thanks!